# Trying to put labels on graph axis in R

Tags: r

I am trying to put a label on my x and y axis. When I make the graph using

```
plot(x,y, type=n)
```

The axes are labelled x and y. I have tried using

```
title(xlab="")
```

but that puts the new title over the top of the old one without removing the old one.

I have tried using NULL and nothing happens. I can't seem to get rid of the existing labels and now  have a graph with several labels over the top of each other. I have no idea how to fix it.

P.S. My data is attached, so I don't have any other parameters in making my graph. I don't have a lot of R knowledge, so simple answers please!

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

put inside plot call

```
plot(x = 1:10, y= 1:10, xlab="xlab", ylab = "ylab")
```